# Which type of questions about Singularity containers are on topic on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, closed-questions, site-recommendation

I asked a question about [Singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_(software)) containers, *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73755321/how-to-grant-group-access-to-a-singularity-instance*, and it was shut down pretty quickly as off-topic.

I wanted to ask about which Stack Exchange site should I post this on instead. I can't think of another Stack Exchange site better suited than Stack Overflow.

In particular, on Stack Overflow there is [a tag for Singularity containers](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/singularity-container/info), but this tag is not present on other Stack Exchange sites like *[Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)* hence I don't think the Unix Stack Exchange site is a better fit for this question.

Did I miss a Stack Exchange site that is better suited for this question?

Comment: Because it is not about programming it's about managing a container and its users. [so] is for programming based questions; this is why the closure reason suggests that it may be on-topic on [another Stack Exchange site](https://stackexchange.com/sites). I'm not familiar enough with Singularity, nor what your question is asking, however, to suggest which would be correct. One of the good places to start is reading a site's tour though.

Comment: As Stack Overflow users, we are not in the best position to guide you to other sites in the network. If your question is about general computing, various aspects of it might be acceptable on [su], [sf], [unix.se], [ubuntu.se], or etc.

Answer (score 7):

> Did I miss a Stack Exchange site that is better suited for this question ?

Most likely Unix & Linux.

> In particular, on Stack Overflow there is a tag for singularity-container, but this tag is not present on other Stack Exchange sites like Unix & Linux hence I don't think Unix stackexchange is a better fit for this question.

Quoting from the question:

> In short, any user in the group `users` should be able to do `singularity run instance:\\myinstance`

**How is that a question about the program**? *Why does it matter* what the program does? Why would the answer *not be the same*, if we replace `singularity` with, say, `firefox`, or `python`?

If it doesn't matter, then the question is "how do I grant these particular sorts of access rights to a program on a Linux system?", which is exactly what that site is for. It's also almost certainly a common duplicate; the relevant commands for granting or denying privileges (including execution) for a file (including executables) to selected users (including "all users in the group with a specific name") are `chmod` and `chown`, and this stuff is about as fundamental as it gets.

On the other hand, if there were some Singularity-specific reason why granting OS-level privileges to run the command doesn't solve the problem - then that is a **tech support** question, and the appropriate place to ask is a Singularity-specific discussion forum, issue tracker, etc.

Comment: I gave the question a title edit. I don't think that edit invalidates your answer but if it does can we discuss the best way forward?

Comment: "How is that a question about the program? " - the only interpretation where it's about the program is if running a specific instance should be restricted, which can only be controlled by the program itself. Changing user groups can control access to the singularity binary, but not subcommands. But even if that's the case here, it would've still needed to be closed, as the actual intent is unclear